# Correct HTTP status code when POST xml is invalid?

Tags: web-services, http, rest

What HTTP status code should I return when a POST request is made to my RESTful API but the content in the POST field (let's say an XML) is invalid?

I would like to build a proper RESTful web service so I want to know.

I am now returning 405 when a HTTP method not supported by specific API is used, 200 when everything goes ok and 500 for all other errors (XML validation error etc).

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't you just return OK and show an error to the user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would respond with 400

> 400 Bad Request
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

Comment: Yep. 400 is most appropriate. In Django, you can do this easily by returning `HttpResponseBadRequest()`

Answer (score -2):

That's what status code 422 is for.

Comment: Status code 422 use for well-formed XML(i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2434-http-status-codes-for-invalid-data-400-vs-422.htm